# Android: How to automatically refresh chat screen when new message in MySQL Database detected

Tags: java, android, mysql, chat

I am working on a android(java) chat app using MYSQL as database. Is there any way to automatically refresh and update the chat screen upon receiving new messages in database without having to reload the entire activity manually?...Like Whatsapp...

Rn upon sending a message, I get all the messages from database again which is not a good approach. But when other user send a message, for me to receive it and get it displayed on my screen I have to manually restart the activity.

Comment: MYSQL is not a realtime database so there is no easy way to do it, You didn't mention your backend also. But you could look in to socket to achieve what you are doing. I recommend switch your database to firebase realtime.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the **WebSocket** protocol to receive real-time changes and reduce costs, chat applications use WebSockets to establish the connection only once for exchange, publishing, and broadcasting the message among the subscribers. It reuses the same WebSocket connection, for sending and receiving the message and for one-to-one message transfer.

**Otherwise**, you can check the existence of a new message every 3 seconds, you can use the id or time of the last message as a criterion for identifying new messages.